# How to get content with ajax from an admin page to all content pages?

Tags: ajax

I want to get content using ajax from an admin page and append it to all content pages on right hand side.

I have this script:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/Quicklinks-Content-Admin',
    type: 'GET',
    success: function(data) {

        var quicklinks_list = [];
        $('.content-inner .blogentries ul li').each(function (i, v) {

            v = $(v);
            quicklinks_list.push({
                text: $('.blogBody a', v).text().trim(),
                href: $('.blogBody a', v).attr("href"),
                bg: $(v).find('.sws-inline-content img').attr('src')
            });

            console.log(i);
            console.log(quicklinks_list[i].text);
            console.log(quicklinks_list[i].href);
            console.log(quicklinks_list[i].bg);

            $(".quicklinks-inner").append('<div class="right-quicklink ql' + i + '"><div class="quicklink-inner"><div class="quicklink-title"><a href="' + quicklinks_list[i].href + '">' + quicklinks_list[i].text + '</a></div><div class="background-cover"></div></div></div>');
            $('.ql'+ i +' .background-cover').css("background-image", 'url("' + quicklinks_list[i].bg + '")');

            $(".quicklink-title a").html(function(index, old) {
                return old.replace(/(\b\w+)$/, '<span class="lastWord">$1</span>');
            });

        });
    }
});
```

With this script I extract the content from a blog list from "/Quicklinks-Content-Admin" page  which is a link in two variable (text and href) and one more variable for the image. After this I want to insert the content from variables to all content pages.

Actually, that script insert the content just for that admin page, instead to put it on every single page.

Why does it happen and how to solve the problem ?

Answer (score 0):

AJAX is just a procedure for sending data from/to the current webpage to a back-end PHP (or aspx etc) file.

If the transmitted data should be remembered (for example, to update other pages), then you can store it in a database and refactor the other pages to read from the database for data when constructing each of those pages.

If you require the AJAX data to be added to other areas on the same page as the AJAX routine, for example in sidebar sections that are `$.load()`ed when the page is constructed, just use javascript to update those areas. Or, use javascript to call another `$.load()` of the data into that div.

Regardless how you do it, you will either use javascript to update an area on the page you are on, or you will store the data on the server *(usually using a database, but you can also use a server-side file)* and make the other PHP pages read that stored information when building their pages.

Comment: Thank you for your advice! Can you provide a tutorial, please?

Comment: Take a look at the free ajax video tutorials on thenewboston.com and on codecourse.com